# Can Conda manage multiple versions of the same package?

Tags: conda, miniconda, root-framework

I’m trying to use two Conda environments, each with a different version of CERN Root, but after setting them up and installing, even if I switch environments, only the first installed version works. I specified the versions upon install and the pkgs/ directory shows both, but I can only run one, and the include directory only shows the headers for one. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This should work; need more details to diagnose. So you have two envs? Can you show us what what happens when you activate each env (show all commands) then run something that attempts using the libraries?  Note: each env has its own `include` directory under the `miniconda3/envs/<yourenv>/include` path.

Comment: I found the issue. The particular package liked to modify the path as it saw fit and previously I had designed another environment manager specifically for it before it was available for Conda. This was aliasing the base Conda version which took precedent  over the one Conda set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an alias that was capturing the original version in the Conda base environment as part of an environment switcher designed before the package was released for Conda. Removing this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A note was [added about this](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/pull/436/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8) on a pull request for Biconda in 2015, saying it is possible to do this. The structure should be as follows:

> If there is interest to keep multiple versions of a package or to explicitly build an older version of a package,
>   you can store those versions in subdirectories of the corresponding recipe, e.g.:

```
java-jdk/
├── 7.0.91
│   ├── build.sh
│   └── meta.yaml
├── build.sh
└── meta.yaml
```

> **There should always be a primary in the root directory of a package that is updated when new releases are made.**